# 'object does not contain a definition for 'InsertParameters'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm just creating grid view dynamic insert value and I'm keep on getting the error 
I don't know what it says.

Welcome.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Welcome.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoApplication.Welcome" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>Database</h1>
            <p>
                &nbsp;
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="156px" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowFooter="True" Width="180px" OnDataBinding="GridView1_DataBinding" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Id">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mail" SortExpression="Mail">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mail") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Mail") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="txtUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" />
                                <asp:Button ID="txtCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="insert" runat="server" OnClick="insert_Click" Text="Insert" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="txtEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
                                <asp:Button ID="txtDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Final]" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Final] ([Name], [Password], [Mail]) VALUES (@Name, @Password, @Mail)">
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Mail" Type="String" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my cs page

> Welcome.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace DemoApplication
{
    public partial class Welcome : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private object SqlDataSource1;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtName")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPassword")).Text;
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtMail")).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error from the below lines

> SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtName")).Text;
>                   SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPassword")).Text;
>                   SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtMail")).Text;

Comment: The error is clear - the `Object` type has no `InsertParameters` method. Use the *correct* type (asp:SqlDataSource ) and ensure the field is initialized. You use Webforms though, which means those fields are already generated. This technology is so old you'll find a *lot* of docs, tutorials and courses showing how to handle data in ASP.NET WebForms. Check [Querying Data with the SqlDataSource Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/querying-data-with-the-sqldatasource-control-cs) for example

Comment: And right below that article, is [Using Parameterized Queries with the SqlDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-cs)